# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list when trying to add a function to sort data

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, jquery-events

I am getting the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

with the below Javascript:

```js
jQuery.extend(cipMonitorErrorsSettings, {
    loadOnStartup: true,
    columnDefs: [{
        "mData": "createdDate",
        "bSortable": true,
        "sTitle": '<fmt:message key="card.cipErrors.createdDate"/>',
        "mRender": function(data, type, cipErrors) { //new
          return '<button class="cipSummary buttonlink createdDate">' + cipErrors.createdDate + '</button>'; //new
        }
      },
      {
        "mData": "status",
        "bSortable": true,
        "sTitle": '<fmt:message key="card.cipErrors.status"/>'
      },
      {
        "mData": "jsonRequest",
        "sTitle": '<fmt:message key="card.cipErrors.jsonRequest"/>'
      },
      {
        "mData": "jsonResponse",
        "sTitle": '<fmt:message key="card.cipErrors.jsonResponse"/>'
      }

    ],
    editLinks: [{ //Edit
      selector: ".cipSummary",
      callback: function(target, data) {
        //  debugger;
        $ {
          prefix
        }
        ActionFormHandler.open(data);
      },
      disabled: $ {
        actionBean.restricted['RESTRICT_EDIT']
      }

    }],
    postInitCallback: function() {
      console.log(this.container.find(".appendImage"));
    },
    actionButtons: {
      exportText: '<fmt:message key="export.csv"/>'
    }


  }
  $(document).ready(function(data) {
    $('#cipTable').DataTable({
      "order": [
        [3, "desc"]
      ],
      "columnDefs": [{
          targets: 0,
          data: "createdDate"
        },
        {
          targets: 1,
          data: "status"
        },
        {
          targets: 2,
          data: "jsonRequest"
        },
        {
          targets: 3,
          data: "jsonResponse"
        }
      ]
    })
  });
);
```

I have checked and double-checked and tried many times, but still cannot get rid of this error. I also added a debugger but can locate where it is happening. I am trying to display the columns but sort by `createdDate` column.

Comment: Your code is fine. Did the error say where to find the `SyntaxError`? And do you have more code than this?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier, I updated with the complete code

Comment: Remove the last `);` before the closing `</script>`. In general browsers (and any decent interpreter/compiler) will tell you the line number for errors. You should learn to debug simple mistakes yourself.

Comment: @junvar well, linting isn't helping in my case as the function call that fails with the error in the title is inside a string literal, using google maps API infoWindow. I know how to debug, but the error in the console just points to line 1 of index.hrml, so not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your script like this, i removed the last ");" at end of script.

```js
jQuery.extend(cipMonitorErrorsSettings, {
    loadOnStartup: true,
    columnDefs: [{
        "mData": "createdDate",
        "bSortable": true,
        "sTitle": '<fmt:message key="card.cipErrors.createdDate"/>',
        "mRender": function(data, type, cipErrors) { //new
          return '<button class="cipSummary buttonlink createdDate">' + cipErrors.createdDate + '</button>'; //new
        }
      },
      {
        "mData": "status",
        "bSortable": true,
        "sTitle": '<fmt:message key="card.cipErrors.status"/>'
      },
      {
        "mData": "jsonRequest",
        "sTitle": '<fmt:message key="card.cipErrors.jsonRequest"/>'
      },
      {
        "mData": "jsonResponse",
        "sTitle": '<fmt:message key="card.cipErrors.jsonResponse"/>'
      }

    ],
    editLinks: [{ //Edit
      selector: ".cipSummary",
      callback: function(target, data) {
        //  debugger;
        $ {
          prefix
        }
        ActionFormHandler.open(data);
      },
      disabled: $ {
        actionBean.restricted['RESTRICT_EDIT']
      }

    }],
    postInitCallback: function() {
      console.log(this.container.find(".appendImage"));
    },
    actionButtons: {
      exportText: '<fmt:message key="export.csv"/>'
    }


  }
  $(document).ready(function(data) {
    $('#cipTable').DataTable({
      "order": [
        [3, "desc"]
      ],
      "columnDefs": [{
          targets: 0,
          data: "createdDate"
        },
        {
          targets: 1,
          data: "status"
        },
        {
          targets: 2,
          data: "jsonRequest"
        },
        {
          targets: 3,
          data: "jsonResponse"
        }
      ]
    })
  });
```